# AutoFitting Columns With Maximum Width Condition?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

In VBA, I want to format my columns across the entire workbook to autofit the data, but with a maximum width of 50 or 75 (no preference as to which width, 50 or 75 are just suggestions). I want to do this because some of my fields can have extensively long values, and I don't want to make it difficult to scroll through the workbook. I don't want to add just a maximum width, because I want cells that are less than that to be autofitted.

I have the code to autofit the columns using a loop in VBA Code, but don't know how to add a maximum width condition.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Sheets("Index").Select
  On Error Resume Next
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next sht
On Error GoTo 0
```

There are no error messages, the code works great. But, I need to add the maximum width condition and I'm unsure how.

Comment: Can you get the value of the column size autofit generates and then run an inner loop if it is above 50 or 75? Not good enough in vba to provide code, just an idea...

Comment: Review this link: [https://a4accounting.com.au/autofit-columns-with-a-limit/](https://a4accounting.com.au/autofit-columns-with-a-limit/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to loop through the used columns to change their widths one at a time:

```
Sheets("Index").Select
  On Error Resume Next
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.AutoFit
         For c = sht.UsedRange.Column To sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
             If sht.Cells(1, c).ColumnWidth > 75 Then sht.Cells(1, c).ColumnWidth = 75
         Next c
    Next sht
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Nice one, plus 1 and forgive me if I borrow it :)

Comment: There may be an easier way to do it. If a sheet has a lot of wide columns, this could be very slow.

Comment: @GregViers I ran your code and no error message came up, but it didn't cut the column width at 75. I wrote 'dim c' at the top of my sub, so I know that there's no issue there. Any ideas as to why it didn't work? Your code is very helpful though! Gives a good foundation.

Comment: There was a bug in it. I was referencing activeSheet, instead of `sht`. I've fixed it.

Comment: @GregViers Hm, don't know why but it still isn't working. There's one column on one of my worksheets with a width of 255. That is the 15th worksheet though, so maybe it's just taking awhile? Again, no error message.

Comment: Is there any data in that column? I'm using `.usedrange`, so an empty column might not get grabbed.

Comment: Nevermind, just found another bug and edited my answer again. Try it now.